# Повторение цикла два раза подряд

Tags: jquery

Задача: повторять анимацию два раза через определённый интервал времени.
У меня работает почему то только один раз каждые 10 секунд

```
var timer_id = setInterval(rem, 10000); // повторение анимации дважды, каждые 10 секунд
                function rem() {
                    function repeat(){
                                     // анимация
                    }

                    function start(){
                     // та же анимация
                                     repeat(); // повторение анимации второй раз
                    };
                    start(); // запуск анимации первый раз
                }
function abortTimer() { 
              clearInterval(timer_id);
            }
```

Comment: а где спрятался вызов фуксии abortTimer?

Comment: дык `clearInterval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из задачи (повторять анимацию два раза через определённый интервал времени)
я бы предложил вам сделать так: ([а рабочий пример можно посмотреть тут](http://jsfiddle.net/pvkovalev/C74Yj/))

HTML:

```
<div class="toggler">
    <div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
         <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Animate</h3>

        <p>Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <button id="btnStop">Stop</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var keepdoing = true;
$(document).ready(function () {
    doit();
});
function doit() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        animate();
    }
    if (keepdoing) {
        timeout_id = setTimeout(doit, 5000); // я сделал 5 сек для наглядности
    }
}
function animate() {
    // анимация
    $("#effect").animate({
        width: 500
    }, 500).animate({
        width: 240
    }, 500);
}
$(document).on('click', '#btnStop', function () {
    keepdoing = false;
})
```

Немного CSS:

```
.toggler {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
#effect {
    width: 240px;
    height: 135px;
    padding: 0.4em;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
}
#effect h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.4em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Надеюсь это поможет.